# Why don't these styling rules work when viewed in TableForm?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

```
m = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10, 10}];
m /. {x__, y_ /; y > 0} -> Style[{x, y}, Red]
% // TableForm
```

When `m` without style , `TableForm` or `Grid` works well on it. But when I set a style, it doesn't work as I expected. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: @andre, I'd suggest putting that as an answer

Comment: As a matter of taste I would rewrite the replacement rule as `m /. l_List /; Last[l] > 0 :> ... `. This formulation already hints at what is the problem with `Style` being applied to a list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
m = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10, 10}];
m /. {x__, y_ /; y > 0} :> (Style[#, Red] & /@ {x, y});
% // TableForm
```

**Explanation about `TableForm[]`**

TableForm[] accepts as argument only a `List[]` of `List[]`.

`m /. {x__, y_ /; y > 0} -> 
  Style[{x, y}, Red]` seems to be a `List[]` of `List[]` :

[image]

but in fact the red lines have a wrapper (`Style[]`) that indicates the color.
Here is the `InputForm` of the same thing :

[image]

The solution is to wrap the color deeper in the expression with

```
m /. {x__, y_ /; y > 0} :> (Style[#, Red] & /@ {x, y}) :
```

It looks like nearly the same :

[image]

But this time we have a `List[]` of `List[]`. Here is the `InputForm` :

[image]

**Small explanation about `:>` and not `->`**

My first attempt was to use :

```
m /. {x__, y_ /; y > 0} ->  (Style[#, Red] & /@ {x, y}
```

with -> instead of :>

It didn't work.

The reason is the ordering of evaluation :

- first  `Style[#, Red] & /@ {x, y}` is evaluated.
  It becomes `{Style[x, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],Style[y, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]}`
- then x is evaluated.
  With x=`Sequence[1,2,3]` for example, it gives

  `Style[1, 2, 3, ... color informations ...]`

  which is not a valid syntax for `Style[]`

Comment: Why not explain why your code works but his does not?

Comment: @DavidCarraher Explanation added. Hope I have explained what should be explained.

Comment: Nice explanation (+1) and you also used :> rather than ->

Comment: @cormullion small explanation about :> and -> added (at the end)

Comment: Excellent - thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As excellently described by andre the problem is that style is applied to the row vectors rather than the array elements themselves, and `TableForm` is not written to handle this situation.  For ease of use you may wish to write a variant of `Style` that automatically threads over lists:

```
style[args__] := Thread[Style[args], List, 1]
```

Now:

```
m = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10, 10}];
m /. a : {__, _?Positive} :> style[a, Red]
% // TableForm
```

Note the simpler pattern form, and the use of `:>` to localize the pattern name `a`.